# Django form submission without reloading page

Tags: django, ajax, forms

I have a django register form .On the event of an invalid form submission, page is reloading.I need to stay on that same page if the data entered is invalid.
Is there any way to get this done without ajax ?
If not, how to do this with ajax

Comment: How else would you know that the form is invalid?
A possibility is to use client form validation in JS and disable the submit button unless all fields are correctly filled.

Comment: hi anandu i dont know if the same can be done without using ajax. but i have done something similar in ajax, a user login form if you want i can share the code with you

Comment: Can you please share your code.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to validate the data before submitting then you can just use plain javascript to validate the values and update your html displaying output as shown below.

Consider this below form.

```
<form>
    <input id="target" type="text" value="">
</form>
<div id="other">
    Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Use below script

```
<script>

    $("#target").keyup(function () {        
        console.log(this.value);
    });

</script>
```

In above script once you get the value you can write the logic to valid the same and update you result in html accordingly.

NOTE: Main point here is the event handler as you type anything it calls the function.

Obviously this may not be the best way to achieve this but consider this as demonstration.